# What are some good ways to handle long values in a dropdown?

Tags: dropdown, drop-down-list

I need to create a dropdown to select various groups and most of them have very long titles.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a tool tip on hover that will show the full text of the truncated text you had on your drop down [image]